# What is the best practice to profile an React Native iOS App?

Tags: ios, react-native

What is the best practice to profile an React Native iOS App? [The official docs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.34/docs/performance.html#profiling) say that I should use Apple xCode's Instruments but I could not really find any good RN related resources on that.

Comment: did you find any valuable resources?

Answer (score -4):

My recomendation is to use [Ignite](https://github.com/infinitered/ignite)

Is a great way to see what are the best practices in React-native projects. It also contains some good dev-screens to learn how to fetch data from APIs.

In this repo you can find all the information needed.

https://github.com/infinitered/ignite

Hope it helps!